# Submodule __init__.py is not passed to scripts

Tags: python, python-module

I have a folder structure defined like below:

```
\test
    main.py
    \module
        __init__.py
        foo.py
```

`main.py` contains:

```
from module.foo import bar
bar()
```

`__init__.py` contains:

```
HELLO = "hello"
```

`foo.py` contains:

```
def bar():
    print(HELLO)
```

When I run in the command line `python main.py` I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'HELLO' is not defined
```

I do not understand then why the `__init__.py` does not pass the `HELLO` variable to `foo.py`

Comment: you should add an import statement in `foo.py`.

Comment: Why did you think it *would*?

Comment: In my understanding of __init__.py in modules, it generates variables that are then made available to the scripts in the same module as the __init__.py. Am I wrong ? If yes how should I proceed ?

Comment: I think that the `__init__.py` is 'executed' by the module which performs the `import`, not the other modules in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define this constant, you need to import your module.

For example:

in `foo.py`, you must:

```
from module import HELLO

def bar():
    print(HELLO)
```

Comment: Thank you, then it also means that my understanding of __init__.py is not correct. I really thought that once you load a module, it run the __init__.py file and makes the result available to all scripts in the same folder. I know understand it is not so simple.

Comment: In my understand of `__init__` it is meant to be the opposite. You declare what are the public functions/classes/variables of your package to the outside world.

Comment: That is exactly the sentence I needed !

Answer (score 1):

In foo.py, add

```
from . import HELLO
```

so the variable `HELLO` is imported.

The fully qualified name of the variable `HELLO` is `module.HELLO`. This mean `HELLO` is defined in the package `module`.